# Cross-compiling kernel tools, cannot find -lelf even with -L set correctly

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, cross-compiling, ld

I'm trying to cross-compile a modified version of the official Debian kernel for armhf on my amd64 machine.  I'm using the [HowToCrossBuildAnOfficialDebianKernelPackage](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToCrossBuildAnOfficialDebianKernelPackage) instructions on the Debian wiki.

The kernel itself builds fine, but I get an error from `ld` when trying to build `objtool` for the `linux-kbuild` package:

```
# make -f debian/rules.real build-kbuild KBUILD_HOSTLDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
[...]
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc /usr/src/linux.buster-backports/debian/build/build-tools/tools/objtool/objtool-in.o -lelf /usr/src/linux.buster-backports/debian/build/build-tools/tools/objtool/libsubcmd.a -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -o /usr/src/linux.buster-backports/debian/build/build-tools/tools/objtool/objtool
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lelf
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:67: /usr/src/linux.buster-backports/debian/build/build-tools/tools/objtool/objtool] Error 1
```

You can see that `make` did add the `-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` flag to `gcc`.  And `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` does contain `libelf`:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libelf*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67296 May 28  2019 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libelf-0.176.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    15 May 28  2019 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libelf.so.1 -> libelf-0.176.so

# file /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libelf-0.176.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libelf-0.176.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=51d60560aa6c0538f0bf34c07e4e2bc230c00834, stripped
```

I installed `libelf` like this:

```
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt-get update
apt-get install libelf1:armhf
```

The `ld` that's being used does appear to be for arm:

```
# /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld -V
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.31.1
  Supported emulations:
   armelf_linux_eabi
   armelfb_linux_eabi
```

I'm stumped.  How do I get `ld` to link `libelf`?

Comment: "And `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` does contain `libelf`" - It doesn't contain a `libelf` library actually. Linking `-lelf` never searches files like `libelf-0.176.so` or `libelf.so.1`. You probably need to create `libelf.so` file, which points to `libelf-0.176.so`.

Comment: Ah, you're right!  I installed the `libelf-dev:armhf` package, which includes the armhf `libelf.so` symlink, and now it links successfully.  (I already had the `libelf-dev:amd64` package installed, but I didn't realize that `-dev` packages contain arch-specific symlinks.)  If you'd like to write your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `libelf-0.176.so` nor `libelf.so.1` are searched by the `-lelf` option to the linker. You still need `libelf.so` file. This file can be created:

- By installing `libelf-dev` package (as usual, the libraries with exact `.so` are installed by `*-dev` packages). Make sure to choose a package suitable for cross-compiling.
- By creating symlink `libelf.so` pointed to the `libelf-0.176.so` file which you have.